# Show that $\lim_{m\to \infty}l_m=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $(a_n)$ a sequence of elements in $\mathbf{R}^*$ such that the sequence $(x_n=a_n\cdot...\cdot a_0)$ converges to $l\in \mathbf{R}^*$. Let $l_m=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_n}{x_m}$. Show that $\lim_{m\to \infty}l_m=1$. So, i would like to know if the following proof holds and correct, please.

As $(x_n)$ converges to $l\in \mathbf{R}^*$, $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. Therefore, by definition we have that: $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists N \ \forall n>m\ge N$:

$|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$

But,

$|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon \iff |\dfrac{x_n}{x_m}-1|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{x_m}\le \epsilon$

Thus, $\lim_{m\to \infty}l_m=1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! The proof is not quite right, first because it must really be $\epsilon/|x_m|$ but the more pressing question is -- what if $|x_m| < 1?$. This can happen if $a_n < 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Arun Bharadwaj Thank you! Oh, i see... If $|x_m|<1$ we can't really bound $\epsilon/x_m$ by $\epsilon$.

Comment: Exactly! So you might want to use the convergence of $\{x_n\}$ a bit more explicitly.

Comment: @Arun Bharadwaj Probably, the fact that $\exists b>0 $ such that $\forall n\in \mathbf{N}\ |(x_n)|\ge b$. But, if i use that, i don't really see how it would change something in inequality..

Comment: Oh i think i see.. the $b$ will simply be simplified in the fraction and so we will obtain $\le \epsilon$

Comment: Bingo! In fact, following your original approach, you can even use the fact that $|x_m|$ converges in $\mathbb{R}^*$ to say that $|x_m| \to l$ where $l \neq 0$. Now, letting $m \to \infty$, we have $|l_m - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{|x_m|} \to \frac{\epsilon}{l}$ which still possesses an arbitrary $\epsilon$, and so the gap can be as small as it wants, and your $l_m$ thus converges to $1$.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much for help!